# How do I convert a varchar of nested json to jsonb, then flatten it?

Tags: postgresql, json

Apache Hop doesn't have rich json processing, so I'm pushing the data to postgres to do the job

With a deeply nested (subset example below) blob of json, how can I flatten, then store the result? I'll retrieve it with Hop and carry on processing. The eventual output is csv.

Something like

> update atable set flat_json = flatten(nested_json) where id = 1;

This snip of jq does it, what is the pg equivalent?

```
echo '[{"value": {
"id":"1",
"desc":"widget",
"colours":[{
     "hue":"red",
     "tint":"light"
     },{
     "hue":"green",
     "tint":"light"
     },{
     "hue":"blue",
     "tint":"dark"
     }],
"isActive":true
}}]' | jq '[.[] |
[leaf_paths as $path | {"key": $path | join("_"), "value": getpath($path)}]
| from_entries]
'

result
[
{
"value_id": "1",
"value_desc": "widget",
"value_colours_0_hue": "red",
"value_colours_0_tint": "light",
"value_colours_1_hue": "green",
"value_colours_1_tint": "light",
"value_colours_2_hue": "blue",
"value_colours_2_tint": "dark",
"value_isActive": true
}
]
```

If this an inelegant idea, is there a concise way to push the json to auto-created columns? (there are about 200) Or, push the nested json to a collection of tables (widgets, colours, more) linked by auto generated foreign keys? The real data has deeper nesting than example shown.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As for the PG equivalent, it is this SQL:

```
with recursive json_tree as
(
    select 
        '[{"value": {
        "id":"1",
        "desc":"widget",
        "colours":[{
             "hue":"red",
             "tint":"light"
             },{
             "hue":"green",
             "tint":"light"
             },{
             "hue":"blue",
             "tint":"dark"
             }],
        "isActive":true
        }}]'::json as json_value, 
        array[]::text[] as json_path
    union all
    select 
        coalesce(t_obj.value, t_array.value) as json_value, 
        t.json_path || coalesce(t_obj.key, (t_array.key - 1)::text) as json_path
    from json_tree t
    left join json_each(case when json_typeof(t.json_value) = 'object' then t.json_value end) t_obj on true
    left join json_array_elements(case when json_typeof(t.json_value) = 'array' then t.json_value end) with ordinality t_array(value, key) on true
    where json_typeof(t.json_value) in ('array', 'object')  
)
select array_to_string(json_path[2:], '_') as json_path_key, json_value #>> '{}' as json_value
from json_tree
where json_typeof(json_value) not in ('array', 'object')
```

The above SQL should work for an arbitrary JSON, and in this case it returns the following:

```
|json_path_key       |json_value|
|--------------------|----------|
|value_id            |1         |
|value_desc          |widget    |
|value_isActive      |true      |
|value_colours_0_hue |red       |
|value_colours_0_tint|light     |
|value_colours_1_hue |green     |
|value_colours_1_tint|light     |
|value_colours_2_hue |blue      |
|value_colours_2_tint|dark      |
```

Recursive SQL is needed, because JSON objects and arrays need to be recursively unpacked. Since the recursive reference to `json_tree` cannot appear twice in the query, we resort to a bit of trickery in this step, with two left joins (of which only one will match a given row), and `case ... when` to ensure `json_each()` and `json_array_elements()` don't receive mismatched parameter types, which would result in an error. (This is not too elegant, I'm wondering if there is a better way to do it.)

The SQL will construct a JSON path as an array, and with `array_to_string()` we finally produce a quasi-column name. (I'm omitting the first element of the path by slicing the array with `json_path[2:]`, because the top-level element in the example JSON is an array, so strictly speaking the correct path keys would be `0_value_id`, `0_value_desc`, etc.)

All JSON paths are produced, but we're interested in leaf nodes only, and - since we know arrays and objects cannot be leaf nodes - we need to exclude them in the end.

As for the second question - namely, if I understand correctly, is this the best way to propagate arbitrary JSON data into a (presumably) matching database schema - my guess is almost certainly not, although:

- additional information would be needed to provide a more reliable answer, and
- a better solution - whatever it might be - will likely rely at least in part on the above SQL

Comment: Wow! An impressive chunk of sql, and indeed quite some trickery, well done.